# Adding intent filter to listen to ACTION_VIEW on SMS events

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am writing an SMS app and it listens to all the AndroidManifest changes required for SMS apps above Kitkat according to the [Google blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).
I was trying to ACTION_VIEW requests related to SMS as well. Something of this format.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + msg.thread_id));
   mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

This is the screen which shows for this call.

[image: Action chooser dialog]

For this call other SMS apps are shown in the Action Chooser dialog, but not my app. What is the scheme to be added to the manifest to list my app to this. 
This is my Manifest portion containing the intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have to add **android:exported** property in you Manifest.xml file. The **android:exported="true"** property will enable your activity to be visible beyond your Application boundary, so that other app can call your activity to resolve similar intent. Add all your mentioned property to your Activity like following and your app will also appear in the Intent resolution screen. The Manifest Code is in below. I'm also attaching a screenshot with my answer.

**Manifest design ---->**

```
<activity android:name=".activities.Experimental"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        <data android:scheme="mms" />
        <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

[image: Here is the screenshot where my app Hoster appear as a choice.]